# From STS, unable to connect to JDBC while running it for a project

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-boot, jdbc

I'm unable to connect to JDBC. I get the below error while trying to connect:

```
Wed Jul 25 16:37:30 IST 2018 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
[2m2018-07-25 16:37:30.821[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m10908[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH000261: Table found: user_experior_dev_sdk.audit_config_request
[2m2018-07-25 16:37:30.821[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m10908[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH000037: Columns: [app_session_id, device_id, condition_status, created_at, task_id, capture_type, id, ip_address, rejection_criteria, message, version_key, status]
[2m2018-07-25 16:37:30.835[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m10908[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH000261: Table found: user_experior_dev_sdk.audit_crash_log_request
[2m2018-07-25 16:37:30.835[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m10908[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH000037: Columns: [crash_log, app_session_id, device_id, crash_log_s3_url, created_at, task_id, id, ip_address, rejection_criteria, message, version_key, status]
[2m2018-07-25 16:37:30.849[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m10908[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH000261: Table found: user_experior_dev_sdk.audit_rejected_recordings
[2m2018-07-25 16:37:30.849[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m10908[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH000037: Columns: [screen_zip_name, app_session_id, screen_desc, device_id, created_at, task_id, ip_address, message, version_key, screen_duration, screen_zip_s3_url, id, rejection_criteria]
[2m2018-07-25 16:37:30.860[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m10908[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH000261: Table found: user_experior_dev_sdk.batch_processing_records
[2m2018-07-25 16:37:30.861[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m10908[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH000037: Columns: [screen_zip_name, screen_zip_s3_key, screen_desc, is_video_present, created_at, task_id, ip_address, priority, message, upload_activity_id, job_instance_id, user_task_id, version_key, screen_duration, screen_zip_s3_url, updated_at, is_error, events_file_found, id, is_subscription_updated, status]
[2m2018-07-25 16:37:30.870[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m10908[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH000261: Table found: user_experior_dev_sdk.device_details
[2m2018-07-25 16:37:30.871[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m10908[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH000037: Columns: [api_level, device_id, user_id, mac_address, os_version, model, id, manufacturer]
[2m2018-07-25 16:37:30.871[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m10908[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Missing column: connection_speed in user_experior_dev_sdk.device_details
[2m2018-07-25 16:37:30.881[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m10908[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.apache.catalina.core.StandardService  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Stopping service Tomcat
[2m2018-07-25 16:37:30.906[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m10908[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.boot.SpringApplication              [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Error handling failed (Error creating bean with name 'zuulRefreshRoutesListener' defined in class org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.ZuulProxyConfiguration: BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cache.config.internalCacheAdvisor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cache/annotation/ProxyCachingConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cache.interceptor.BeanFactoryCacheOperationSourceAdvisor]: Factory method 'cacheAdvisor' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException)
[2m2018-07-25 16:37:30.907[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m10908[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.boot.SpringApplication              [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Missing column: connection_speed in user_experior_dev_sdk.device_details
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
```

Below is my POM file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>org.test</groupId>
<artifactId>user-experior-jobs</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>User Experior Jobs</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.userexperior.common</groupId>
        <artifactId>user-experior-common</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <!-- <exclusions> <exclusion> <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId> 
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId> </exclusion> </exclusions> -->
    </dependency>
    <!-- <dependency> <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId> <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId> 
        <version>2.2.3</version> </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId> 
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId> <version>2.2.3</version> </dependency> 
        <dependency> <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId> <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId> 
        <version>2.2.3</version> </dependency> -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-session</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-redis</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId> <artifactId>groovy</artifactId> 
        </dependency> -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring Batch unit test -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-batch-test</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>19.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.redisson</groupId>
        <artifactId>redisson</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpmime -->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-io -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpmime</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
        <version>4.4.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-logging/commons-logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-cli</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-cli</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    <jackson.version>2.6.0</jackson.version>
    <start-class>com.userexperior.jobs.UserExperiorJobsApplication</start-class>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <compilerId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</compilerId>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                    <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</artifactId>
                    <version>2.8.0-01</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                    <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-batch</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1.8-01</version>
                </dependency>

            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings 
                only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself. -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>
                                        org.apache.maven.plugins
                                    </groupId>
                                    <artifactId>
                                        maven-compiler-plugin
                                    </artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>
                                        [3.1,)
                                    </versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <ignore></ignore>
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone-local</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

I have configured it to connect to the database I created but it still fetches from another database, followed by the above error.

My database, that I created and pointed to is: `user_experior_local_sdk`.

Whereas in error it shows: `Table found: user_experior_dev_sdk`

Comment: Well the error is _Missing column: connection_speed in user_experior_dev_sdk.device_details_

Where are you configuring the database URL ?

Comment: i use my mysql workbench where i created a schema and it should point to my db

Comment: Where in your program code is the database URL configured ?

Comment: I got the solution for this as i just needed to mention the correct sql version <version>8.0.11<version> for sql config, the version must be matching to the connector you use for mysql